# Configuration is missing run command in eclipse remote debugging

Tags: eclipse, ide, pbs

Software: Eclipse Scientific Computing + PTP 2023/09

HPC runs on PBS Pro 2021.1.0.XXXX

A new demo MPI fortran projected (synchronized) is created using file wizard and added debug configuration with remote debugging on an HPC. A custom-made job script for PBS Pro is given. When I start debugging, it always throws this error.

[image]

But I am able to run and submit the job successfully with the same configuration on the HPC.

`Run As > Run Configurations > RunMPI`

Error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.29.0.20230907-1200
java.version=21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.parallel.product --help
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.parallel.product --help

org.eclipse.ptp.core
Error
Mon Mar 04 14:28:51 IST 2024
Configuration is missing run commands for job submission d77e0012-a1b7-42a6-b2b5-65cc5541f552 debug
```

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with `eclipse.buildId=` and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like `<`). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform (PTP) project has been archived](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.ptp), so you can fork it but it does not make sense to report bugs to it. You might try to run your Eclipse IDE with Java 17 rather than with Java 21 (since Java 9 there is no 100% backwards compatibility), even if it is unlikely that this will help. If you have a working debug configuration, you can compare it with the one that is not working.

Comment: The error ["Configuration is missing run commands for job submission"](https://github.com/eclipse-ptp/ptp/blob/47cda24d74701d40908ccffaf45cbb55a14aa387/rms/org.eclipse.ptp.rm.jaxb.control.core/src/org/eclipse/ptp/internal/rm/jaxb/control/core/messages/messages.properties#L4) is thrown [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ptp/ptp/blob/47cda24d74701d40908ccffaf45cbb55a14aa387/rms/org.eclipse.ptp.rm.jaxb.control.core/src/org/eclipse/ptp/internal/rm/jaxb/control/core/LaunchController.java#L312).

Comment: @howlger locally I can debug the serial code, but for parallel code I don't have any working configuration. Thanks for pointing to where this error pops from, I don't know where is the problem. This (PTP) project is archived but Eclipse Scientific Computing largely depends on it, which is still under developement.